# Customized Distributable packages

Tags: 12.04, installation

My aim is to have all my installed software packages in a distributable CD / DVD fashion, so that I can install a clean Ubuntu 12 on any system and then use the distributable package CD to get me all that I want.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`AptonCD`](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/aptoncd) [image: Install aptoncd].

It helps you create a CDs/DVDs of your installed packages for later use.

You can also easily choose which packages you want to be backed up in the disk

[image]

---

**Sources**

[Debianadmin](http://www.debianadmin.com/create-backup-of-all-packages-using-aptoncd-in-ubuntu.html)

[Addictivetips](http://www.addictivetips.com/ubuntu-linux-tips/aptoncd-create-backup-of-any-installed-packages-in-ubuntu-linux/)